# Vuejs + Laravel + HTML

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

Hello Stackoverflow community, i need to use Vue Axios / Resource, i managed to make a HTML select box loaded from my database in my view, after i select any record i need to use another value from that record and put it into an HTML input, for example: in my html select i click on my "stpr_tx_descripcion" attribute, after that i need another atribute, the "stpr_in_ticket", but i don't know how make it dynamically.

This is what i got so far:

Im using Laravel to return a query object to my view like this:

```
$query= spr_tipo_per_rep::all('stpr_tx_descripcion','stpr_in_ticket');
    ->with('query',$query);
```

In my view im using the Html select which loads the record:

```
<select  v-model="descripcion" >
    <option value="">Select value</option>
    @foreach($query as $data)              
        <option value="{{ $data->stpr_tx_descripcion }}">{{ $data->stpr_tx_descripcion }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Below that i need to put the value from "stpr_in_ticket" atribute which is another detail into my input using vue:

```
<input type="text" v-model="???" readonly="readonly">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use v-model='ticket' in the select instead of descripcion and then in the value of the select options use {{ $data->stpr_in_ticket }}. That way 'ticket' would always have the value you are looking for. 
Then in the input just put:

```
<input type="text" :value="ticket" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: No, because i need the value from "stpr_tx_descripcion" and also the value from "stpr_in_ticket" after i select that record to be reflected into an input. So i need to make some kind of asynchronus query with Vue to the two values from the same record, it's like when you select a person name on a select and another value like it's Gender it's reflected into another field, it's part from the same record but a different attribute.